# Flutter - Take a photo

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

When I tap on a GestureDetector it opens a dialog where I am able to select, if I want to take the picture from the gallery or to make a photo on my own ([the plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker)). But my problem is when I click on one of the buttons on the dialog, the dialog pops up again and only after that, it's possible to take a picture from the camera or the gallery.
It would be great, if someone could help me with this problem.

This is the **GestureDetector**:

```
GestureDetector(
              child: Container(
                child: (_image == null
                  ? CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.photo))
                  : FileImage(_image)
                )
              ),
              onTap: () async{
                switch(await dialogs.takePhoto(context)){
                  case "take":
                    getImage(ImageSource.camera);
                    break;
                  case "pick":
                    getImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                    break;
                }
              },
            )
```

The call `dialogs.takePhoto(context)` ends here:

```
takePhoto(BuildContext context){
  return showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext ctxt){
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Change Photo"),
          content: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                InkWell(
                  child: Text("Take photo"),
                  onTap: ()=> Navigator.pop(ctxt, "take"),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  child: Text("Pick photo"),
                  onTap: ()=> Navigator.pop(ctxt, "pick"),
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  "Abort"
                ),
                onPressed: ()=>Navigator.pop(ctxt),
            )
          ],
        );
      }
  );
}
```

This is an example:[image: This is an example]

Thanks in advance !

**SOLUTION**

Found the solution exactly the moment where I clicked on the submit button. The problem was that I called the function to pick the image twice XD.

Comment: You can answer it by separately tapping `answer this question`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution exactly the moment where I clicked on the submit button. The problem was that I called the function to pick the image twice XD.